# Is the Qt source code complete?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create some custom widgets for my Qt application and thus I need to reimplement some slots.
Now I searched the [Qt source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source) and found i.e. the cpp file of QSlider ([see here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/f7b3072924fb57b3979ff4d536eb213270be1047%3asrc/gui/widgets/qslider.cpp)). I looked for the implementation of `setValue(int)`, and it is mentioned in the comments a few times, but I couldn't find the implementation.
This led me to the conclusion that either the source code is not complete or that I'm missing something.

Comment: The source is absolutely complete. Kind of pointless to build if it was missing parts. And I have built Qt dozens of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `setValue` is inherited from `QAbstractSlider`, you can see its source [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/f7b3072924fb57b3979ff4d536eb213270be1047%3asrc/gui/widgets/qabstractslider.cpp).